# Difference between user_posts & user_status

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I am confused if `user_status` permission is useful by any mean. I tried `user_posts` and that works fine but `user_status` do not work. 
I do not know if I am missing something. I have tried it on Graph API Explorer.

**What I want to know?**

How to use just `user_status` permission? As per Facebook references user_status

`Provides access to a person's statuses. These are posts on Facebook which don't include links, videos or photos.`

**What I know already?**

By getting user_posts permission I successfully got status updates and other posts by fetching node data for `/me/feed` .

**EDIT:**

By saying `user_status` do not work, I mean that when I use `/me/feed` I should get status of mine(not other type of posts), but I do not get anything.

Comment: What does "`user_status` doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: @Tobi, I have updated my question, pls check edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission `user_status` is no longer available in v2.4 of the Graph API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> GET `/v2.4/{id}/links` and `GET /v2.4/{id}/statuses` will no longer be available beginning in v2.4. As an alterantive, we suggest using `GET /v2.4/{id}/feed`.

So, you should use `/{id}/feed` together with the `user_posts` permission as suggested. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed/#read

for the docs. You can use the `filter` parameter if you just want the statuses for example:

```
/{id}/feed?filter=app_2915120374
```